# Should each .Net Project in Solution have it´s own OutputFolder or not?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, csproj

I have a solution with round about 50 Projects.

The default behavior of Visual Studio is to build each project into the project subfolders `bin/debug` and `bin/release`.

In my company there are guidelines that all projects should end up in a common output directory. The advantage should be that the files are not copied so often.
This is done defining the `<OutputDirectory>` in the .csproj file.

Checking the buildoutput showed me many deletes and copies of the same file. So I would expect that there are no advantages in copy count.

So are there any other benefits by sharing the output directory? Are there any problems that I not noticed yet?
What is the best practice handling this?

Thanks for your help :D

Comment: This kind of question are opinion-based usually

Comment: `But it is possible to change this and build all projects into a shared folder` ← Yes but perhaps it would be better to elaborate on *why* you want to do this. What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski my intention was not to get an opinion. I want to get hard pros and cons to argue in my company.

Comment: @R00st3r IMO, it's better to ask it on https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

You can do this simply by using the MSBuild switch `--output` and specifying a folder for all the outputs when building a project/solution. All the dependent projects etc will be built and copied into one output folder.

I don't think it's particularly relevant "to reduce the number of files that are copied" - hard disks copy files all day, every day. Outputting into one folder can have a benefit when packaging for release; our Jenkins build server bundles all files into one folder before it puts them in a package (zip) file for Octopus deploy

You need to be careful htough, because it's possible for different projects to be dependent on different versions of the same DLL, and by mashing all the files together in one folder, DLLs of the same name (but different version) overwrite each other. You can then end up with a situation where your app doesn't load because it's trying for find XYZ DLL version 1.0 and some other project has a reference to version 1.1, and because that project built later, it's the 1.1 version of the DLL that ends up in the folder. You can then experience runtime errors indicating "The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference" - it's saying "I was looking for 1.0, I found a DLL with the right name, but the version of the one I found was 1.1"

This can usually be solved with binding redirects, but it isn't 100% guaranteed that future versions of DLLs are backwards compatible with earlier versions. If you're arranging all your DLLs to copy into one folder youre creating a bit of a lottery for yourself as to whether things will break in production, when DLL versions go out of sync with what you expect

If your company operates a build and deploy process that uses locally copied versions of DLLs then it might be that they insist you do copy all DLLs to one folder to prove that the app will work in production - this is a much better reason (i.e. arrange a way for you to break the dev server so you can see and fix problems caused by DLL versions before putting to production and hitting the same) than "because we don't want the hard disk to get tired copying extra files"

Answer (score -1):

If you insist to do that. You can

- Right Click Your Project
- Choose "Properties" => "Build Events" => "Post-build event command line"
- Put xcopy "$(ProjectDir)\bing\debug{yourprojectdll}" "{path to shared folder}" /Y /I /R

Comment: I don´t have a problem building to a shared folder (it is done by setting the OutputPath in the csproj) but I do not really know what are the pros and cons of doing this.

Comment: The pros of having a shared folder is you don't need to add your project to your solution. You just need to add reference to the project DLL in your shared folder. This can save you lots of time while developing. Since you don't need to rebuild the referenced project (if you reference DLL).